# simple jQuery dropdown menu using toggleClass

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the below code but my problem is that when I hover on one menu all submenu's open in the dropdown, how do I only toggleClass active on the specific menu button I click:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("ul li").hover(function() {
      // remove classes from all
      $("nav li:first").toggleClass("active");

    });
  });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
  .container nav li {display: none;}
  .container nav li.active {display:block;}
</style>
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>1</span>
      <nav><li>sub 1</li>
      </nav>
    </li>

    <li>
      <span>2</span>
      <nav><li>sub 1</li>
        <li>sub 2</li>
      </nav>
    </li>

  </ul>


</div>
```

Comment: A `<li>` element **can not** be a direct child of a `<nav>` element, the only valid parents for a `<li>` element is `<ul>` or `<ol>`, meaning you have totally invalid HTML, and who knows what can happen when the markup is invalid.

Comment: yes i just did a rough markup for now but I wanted to know how to do the jquery can you please help just with the jquery?

Answer (score 0):

**Change :**

```
 $("nav li:first").toggleClass("active");
```

**to :**

```
$("nav li",this).toggleClass("active");
```

**Final code :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $("ul li").hover(function() {
        // remove classes from all
        $("nav li",this).toggleClass("active");

    })
    
})
```

```css
.container nav li {display: none;}
.container nav li.active {display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span>1</span>
            <nav>
                <li>sub 1</li>
            </nav>
        </li>
        
        <li>
            <span>2</span>
            <nav>
                <li>sub 1</li>
                <li>sub 2</li>
            </nav>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `<nav>` show hide instead of `<li>`. Therefore, Apply active class on `<nav>` tag.

Please check below snippet for more details. Made change in css and jquery code accordingly.

```js
$(function() {
  $("ul li").hover(function() {
    $("nav").removeClass("active");
    // remove classes from all
    $(this).find("nav").toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.container nav{display: none;}
.container nav.active {display:block;padding-left:25px;}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>1</span>
      <nav><li>sub 1</li>
      </nav>
    </li>

    <li>
      <span>2</span>
      <nav>
        <li>sub 1</li>
        <li>sub 2</li>
      </nav>
    </li>

  </ul>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this only using CSS, please follow the code below

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li>
          <a href="#">menu1</a>
            <nav>
            <li>sub 1</li>
            </nav>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#">menu2</a>
            <nav>
                 <li>sub 1</li>
                 <li>sub 2</li>
            </nav>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
li{
    transition:0.3s ease-In-Out;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.container nav li {
    display: none;
}
.container nav li.active {
    display:block;
}
ul li:hover nav li{
    display:block;
}
```

**Check this link for live demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/1235aamp/